# Can't get richTextBox1 to update

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a program that shuts down the computer after the entered amount of time (hours, minutes and seconds). Everything works except it doesn't update richTextBox1 at all. Please could someone help with this issue. Thanks in advance.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Timers;

namespace ShutdownPC
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public int inputHours = 0;
        public int inputMinutes = 0;
        public int inputSeconds = 0;
        public int totalSeconds = 0;
        public int totalMilliseconds = 0;
        public int ticks = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Enabled = false;
            textBox2.Enabled = false;
            textBox3.Enabled = false;
            button1.Enabled = false;

            // Hours
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text))
            {
                inputHours = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            }

            // Minutes
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox2.Text))
            {
                inputMinutes = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
            }

            // Seconds
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox3.Text))
            {
                inputSeconds = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);
            }

            // Updating richTextBox1 every second with remaining time left
            totalSeconds = (inputHours * 3600) + (inputMinutes * 60) + inputSeconds;
            timer1.Start();
            while (ticks < totalSeconds)
            {
                TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(totalSeconds);

                string timeOutput = time.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");

                richTextBox1.AppendText(String.Format(timeOutput));
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                richTextBox1.Clear();
            }


            // Shutting down computer
            totalMilliseconds = ((inputHours * 3600) + (inputMinutes * 60) + inputSeconds) * 1000;
            Thread.Sleep(totalMilliseconds);
            richTextBox1.AppendText("end");
            //Process.Start("shutdown", "/s /t 0");
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ticks++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't block on the UI thread.

Comment: When would you expect to see the new text? Right after the sleep, yes?? that is when??? Did you give the rzb time to refresh? Or enforce it?

Comment: BTW: When blocking the UI thread, you don't only block the update of UI, you also block the System.Windows.Forms.Timer :)

Comment: The timer is on a 1 second interval so I would expect to see the text every second while the timer is counting down. The timer should count down before the program runs `richTextBox1.AppendText("end");`

Comment: How am I blocking the UI thread? Sorry, new to C#.

Comment: `Thread.Sleep` is a blocking call, It blocks all operations on the running thread (In your case UI thread)

Comment: Oh alright thanks, makes sense yeah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As SLaks told, if you block the UI thread the box will never be updated, but in .net you have await/async, just convert your method to `private async void button1_Click` and instead of `Thread.Sleep` use `await Task.Delay`.

Also, you set the box content with

```
TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(totalSeconds);
richTextBox1.AppendText(String.Format(timeOutput));
```

This should be

```
TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(totalSeconds - ticks);    
richTextBox1.AppendText(String.Format(timeOutput));
```

If you want a count-down.

Comment: @Conor I hate those kind of comments, What does `This didn't work` mean?  Compile time errors? Any exceptions? How have you used that code?

Comment: Look at my update, and other time tell what is *doesn't works* ;)

Comment: This makes the textbox show the first time, then doesn't change until it's finished. For example if I enter 4 seconds, it will show 00:00:04 and then it shows "end", not updating in 1 second intervals.

Comment: sorry I had to go do something, was going to expand on the comment.

Comment: First of all, if the answer was right accept it ;). Second, that's another problem, S.O. works with questions about concrete problems, so create a new question :)

Comment: Alright thanks, yeah makes sense. It does count down so I'll ask another question. Sorry if I came across rude, it really wasn't intended. Thanks for all the help :)

Comment: A comment @Conor, why do you have a timer and a tick variable? if you remove the timer and the tick variables and you do `TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(totalSeconds--);` and change the wile as `while(totalSeconds > 0)` you will achieve the same result but with a source of errors less.

Comment: @Gusman Or like in old days without async/await. Just use a timer without while loop.

Comment: @Gusman Wow thanks, you just fixed everything. It now works as intended. Yeah, I'm still new to C# so I'm making mistakes, getting there :D Thanks for the help, really appreciate it.